# Is it grammatical to use the word "minimize" as a noun?

Tags: grammar

It sounds like the video is [speaking](https://youtu.be/_7JKYazD0ew?t=40) (00:00:40)

> Global **minimize** has been reached.

I understand its meaning. I cannot understand the grammar. Is it grammatical to use the word "minimize" as a noun?

Comment: It is not clear (too much background music) but I think it says "global minimum has been reached". It definitely does not say 'minimize'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not. ‘Minimize’ is a verb, and while some verbs can be nouns, this one can’t. Alternative forms that have a similar meaning and would be grammatically correct in that situation might be ‘minimum’ or ‘minimisation’, so

> The global minimum has been reached.

Or

> Global minimisation has been reached.

Take care that you don’t mix them up, however; they have slightly different meanings. The first would imply that there was a lower limit, and it had been reached, not necessarily by humans, but the second would imply that a lower limit has been reached, probably by humans, and probably as something positive.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you. I believe you are right on the aspect of grammar. I just would like know what that speaker  is saying. Did you listen to that video? It does not sound like minimum or minimization.

Comment: It sounds a bit like 'the global minima has been reached' which is even more nosensical than what you first suggested. That is a very low quality video. Is the narrator a native speaker?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thank you. I don't know any other info about the narrator. Anyway,  "minima" sounds good to me, "minima" is a noun here, right?

Comment: Minima is a plural noun using the Latin -a plural ending (scientists often use maxima, minima, phenomena, etc). It is equivalent to 'minimums'; if it was the word spoken, then the verb after should be 'have' (global minima have been reached). That is what I meant by 'nonsensical'. Such errors are common among native speakers, who, for example, confuse 'phenomenon' (singular) and 'phenomena' (plural).