# Is it idiomatic to say "I don't know any other info about the narrator"?

Tags: idiomatic-language

An answerer asked in a [post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/242884/110470)

> Is the narrator a native speaker

The only thing I know about the narrator is that he is the narrator of that video, so I replied

> I don't know any other info about the narrator.

Is it a idiomatic way to express that meaning?

Comment: 'I don't know anything else' or 'I have no other info(rmation).'

Comment: 'Info' for 'information' is informal/casual/conversational.

Comment: You can know something, or have information. It's not natural to say you know information. In teacher-speak, "information" collocates with the verb "have", and does not collocate with "know".

Answer (score 1):

It is generally more idiomatic to say that you "have info(rmation)" rather than that you "know info(rmation)", so it would be better to say:

> I don't **have** any other info about the narrator.

Alternately, it is more idiomatic to "know things" rather than "know info(rmation)", so you could say:

> I don't know **anything** else about the narrator.